# I am not getting radio value for count answer

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a quiz application using MySQL, PHP and HTML. I designed and coded the quiz application; but I don't know how to get radio value to calculate the correct and wrong value. My frontend coding is:

```
<form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
    <?php

        $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT $start, $perpage") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                $number = 0; 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){           
                        extract($row);  
                        $number++
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                            <h4><?php echo $number;?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }       
            }   
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='ans'>Finish</button>        
    </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image: Quiz Application]

<kbd>Database design</kbd>

[image: quiz table]

Comment: Assuming, that each question has a unique id, you can use the `$_POST` of  `$row['id']` to see, which value is checked.

Comment: you missed at least 1 semicolon in your syntax, and does `extract()` do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
        <?php

            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT $start, $perpage") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));

                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                    $number = 0; 
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){           
                            extract($row);  
                            $number++
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                                <h4><?php echo $number;?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                                <input type="radio" name="ans_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="ans_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="ans_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="ans_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }       
                }   
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='ans'>Finish</button>        
        </div>
    </form>


On php file backend_quiz.php you can get using

<?php echo $_POST['ans_'.$questionId]; ?>

will get value of radio button you have selected
```

Comment: getting error you suggest code Notice: Undefined variable: questionId in D:\xamp\htdocs\bombaytales\includes\backend_quiz.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: ans_ in D:\xamp\htdocs\bombaytales\includes\backend_quiz.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question is 
1. You want to get the answer selected by user
2. Check if the answer matches the correct answer from database value

For 1 you can use $_POST of $row[id] as mentioned by Geshode. 
For 2 I would be doing something like this

1. Store all the question id and selected answer in array variable on submit
2. compare the user answers with database correct answer something like 
   `SELECT * FROM quiz_table WHERE answer=$user_ans;`

   if the count matches you know that it is the correct answer, now you can stuff like score++ or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
    <?php

        $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT $start, $perpage") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                $number = 0; 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){           
                        extract($row);  

                        ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                            <h4><?php echo $number;?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                            <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $number?>]" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $number?>]" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $number?>]" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $number?>]" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        $number++;
                    }       
            }   
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='ans'>Finish</button>        
    </div>
</form>
```

To access the posted values, you can simply use $_POST['question']

Considering the selection for 5 questions to be **Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, Option 1, Option 2** POST['question'] will give array like

> Array ( [1] => a [2] => b [3] => c [4] => a [5] => b )

To access single values from this array, you can use foreach loop as,

```
<?php 
 foreach($_POST['question'] as $option_num => $option_val)
    echo $option_num." ".$option_val."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: after name="questionId" you can answered one question. Second answered automatically deselected.

Comment: I change my answer Please check @Milind

Answer (score 0):

You should send answers as an array.

Below is the corrected code. Hope it works

```
<form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
    <?php

        $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT $start, $perpage") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
                $number = 0; 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){           
                        extract($row);  
                        $number++
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                            <h4><?php echo $number;?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $row['id']?>]" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $row['id']?>]" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $row['id']?>]" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $row['id']?>]" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }       
            }   
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='ans'>Finish</button>        
    </div>
</form>
```

and on server you can get values using `$_POST['answers'][$question_id]`

Comment: You mean like that? <?php
 
 include_once("dbconfig.php");
 
 if(isset($_POST['ans'])){
  $answ= $_POST['ansr'][$question_id];
  echo $answ;
 }
?>

Comment: <?php include_once("dbconfig.php"); if(isset($_POST['answers']) && is_array($_POST['answers'])){ $answ= $_POST['answers'][$question_id]; echo $answ; } ?>